# Why fillna have no effect after several operators on dataframe series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe which look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 
                   'Direction': ['UP', 'DOWN', 'UP', 'UP', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'DOWN', 'UP', 'DOWN', 'UP'],
                   'group':[1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]})
```

Everything works fine, when i do:

```
df['prev'] = df[(df.Event == 'A') & (df.Direction == 'UP')].groupby('group').cumcount().add(1)
df['prev'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

But if i do it in one line the fillna() function does not works:

```
df['prev'] = df[(df.Event == 'A') & (df.Direction == 'UP')].groupby('group').cumcount().add(1).fillna(0)
```

My questioni is: Why is that? And is there a way to do it in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this part `df[(df.Event == 'A') & (df.Direction == 'UP')]` is filtering only rows for Event `A` and Direction `UP` so when you put the `fillna(0)` at the end, you are only replacing `NaN` in the filtered subset of rows and the rest will be filled with `NaN` because the column `prev` didn't exist prebiously.

Also because the column `prev` didn't exist prebiously, I think you cannot do this in a single line. What you are doing is create a whole column and modify only a subset of the same column which you would have to break in 2 steps.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output at this step:

```
print(df[(df.Event == 'A') & (df.Direction == 'UP')].groupby('group').cumcount().add(1))

# Output:
0    1
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Do you see any `nan` values to fill? Is adding `.fillna(0)` here going to do anything?

---

A one liner that would work:

```
df['prev'] = df.assign(prev = df[(df.Event == 'A') & (df.Direction == 'UP')].groupby('group').cumcount().add(1))['prev'].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure why it's not working, but I have a rough idea. In your first idea, this is what is happening:

```
df['prev'] = df[...]...
df['prev'] = df['prev'].fillna(0)
```

Your second idea:

```
df['prev'] = df[...]....fillna(0)
```

This probably has something to do with placing `fillna(0)` on the whole dataframe and when transferred over to the new variable (column) `prev`, it will revert the `0.0` back to `NaN`.